# If I have a favicon, do I need to link to it?

Tags: asp.net, performance, favicon

I have a Favicon and in my page I have something like:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

This works fine. But inspired by the book "Ultra Fast asp" I am trying to remove all the small bits that are not necessary. I read a lot about browsers looking for favicon.ico anyway. (People complaining about 404 errors if they do not have a favicon).

So I was wondering: what is the use of the link if the browser looks for it anyway. It is "dead wood" -> so can I just remove this link completely or am I missing something.

thanks for your ideas,
Pleun

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the explicit link syntax allows you to use *different* icons on different pages, and to have icon support on the browsers that do not automatically download the `favicon.ico` that is in the root of the site.

If you only ever use one icon on a website and don't care about browsers that do not automatically download the root icon, the links are not needed.

Comment: interesting to have different ones. I did not think about that. And what browsers do not automatically download the root icon

Comment: @Pleun - all the popular ones do download it, but some of the lesser used/known do not.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your favicon is in the root of your website (ie. `/favicon.ico`), then yes you can drop this link. The link allows you to change where you want to store your favicon.

Answer (score 0):

The standard specified by W3C uses the link tag rather than automagically look for the file in the root, but all major browsers will support both ways.

The [Wikipedia article about favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) is a good overview of the possibilities and the browser support.